# How to retrieve multiple tags from a database?

Tags: mysql, database

Alright, I have done some research and found out that a good normalized articles and tags table should be like this:

```
articles table:  article_id | article_text

tags table: tag_id | tag_text

article-tag table: article_id | tag_id
```

Now, what I try to do is this: let's say I am searching for 3 tags for example, "asp.net", ".net", "c#". It is very easy to retrieve articles which has these tags. But I don't want this. What I want is to retrieve articles which has ***exactly*** these three tags or ***any two or one of them*** but not articles with 4 or more tags including them. I don't want a search result with "asp.net", ".net", "c#", "ruby". I want only following tagged articles:

```
"asp.net", ".net", "c#"

.net", "c#"

"asp.net", ".net"

"asp.net", "c#"

"c#"

"asp.net"

".net"
```

What would be the right MySQL query for that?

Comment: Maybe make an auxiliary function to count matching tags (from a list of admissible tags) and then select based on the count being 2 or 3.

Comment: I thought that too, and I conclude that I really need to count matching tags. That's the first step, but what about the rest?

Thank you for editing the post by the way (I am a newbie:)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that a [self join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Self-join) might be the way. If you were querying by three tags, you would join the article-tag table with itself 3 times, for example. I'm not sure how this would scale, though.

Update: with this approach you would need to do a second query to exclude those matches with > 3 tags.

Comment: Well then, if I would to search for 6 tags, I would join article-tag table 6 times. Is it optimized? I mean is it the right way to do it?